# The application crashes

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I have problem with application that crashes while opening the next activity. here is the code and android monitor.

```
package com.blabber.app.login;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.blabber.app.BlabberApplication;
import com.blabber.app.MyFirebaseMessagingService;
import com.blabber.app.R;
import com.blabber.app.activities.AddUserNameActivity;
import com.blabber.app.activities.ProfileActivity;
import com.blabber.app.business_details.BusinessDetailsActivity;
import com.blabber.app.data.ConnectionManager;
import com.blabber.app.data.model.User;
import com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity;
import com.blabber.app.login.DaggerLoginComponent;
import com.blabber.app.login.LoginContract;
import com.blabber.app.login.LoginPresenterModule;
import com.blabber.app.splash.DaggerFacebookLoginComponent;
import com.blabber.app.utils.NavigationManager;
import com.blabber.app.utils.Utils;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.blabber.app.BlabberApplication;
import com.blabber.app.R;
import com.blabber.app.signup.SignUpActivity;
import com.blabber.app.utils.ActivityUtils;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginContract{

    private static final String TYPE_FRIEND_REQUEST = "1";
    private static final String TYPE_FRIEND_REQUEST_ACCEPTED = "2";
    private static final String TYPE_FRIEND_REVIEW_TAG = "3";
    private static final String TYPE_NEW_BUSINESS = "4";


    @Inject
    LoginPresenter mLoginPresenter;
    LoginFragment mLoginFragment;
    LoginContract.Presenter mPresenter;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_fb_login)
    Button mFacebookLoginButton;
    @BindView(R.id.signin_tv)
    TextView mSignInTextView;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mLoginFragment = (LoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contentFrame);
        if (mLoginFragment == null) {
            mLoginFragment = LoginFragment.newInstance();
            ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(
                    getSupportFragmentManager(), mLoginFragment, R.id.contentFrame);
        }

        DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
                .dataRepositoryComponent(((BlabberApplication) getApplication()).getUserDataRepositoryComponent())
                .loginPresenterModule(new LoginPresenterModule(mLoginFragment))
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getString("type") != null) {
            String type = getIntent().getExtras().getString("type");

//                E/MainActivity:: Key: google.sent_time Value: 1490611439936
//                03-27 12:44:16.082 27240-27240/? E/MainActivity:: Key: from Value: 723381489363
//                03-27 12:44:16.082 27240-27240/? E/MainActivity:: Key: type Value: 3
//                03-27 12:44:16.082 27240-27240/? E/MainActivity:: Key: review_id Value: 37
//                03-27 12:44:16.082 27240-27240/? E/MainActivity:: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1490611439943980%923c630a923c630a
//                03-27 12:44:16.082 27240-27240/? E/MainActivity:: Key: business_id Value: 368
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_FRIEND_REQUEST:
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("friend_id") != null)
                        openFriendProfile(getIntent().getExtras().getString("friend_id"));

                    break;
                case TYPE_FRIEND_REQUEST_ACCEPTED:
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("friend_id") != null)
                        openFriendProfile(getIntent().getExtras().getString("friend_id"));
                    break;
                case TYPE_FRIEND_REVIEW_TAG: {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in TYPE_FRIEND_REVIEW_TAG");
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("business_id") != null) {
                        openBusiness(getIntent().getExtras().getString("business_id"));
                        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in business_id: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("business_id"));

                    }

                }
                break;
                case TYPE_NEW_BUSINESS:
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("business_id") != null)
                        openBusiness(getIntent().getExtras().getString("business_id"));
                    break;
            }
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                Log.e("MainActivity: ", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);

            }

        }
//        }
        else {

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.wait));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

            DaggerLoginComponent.builder().dataRepositoryComponent(((BlabberApplication) getApplication()).getUserDataRepositoryComponent())
               .loginPresenterModule(new LoginPresenterModule((LoginContract.View) this)).build().inject(this);

            if (Utils.isLoggedBefore(this)) {
                NavigationManager.goToMainActivity(LoginActivity.this);
            } else {
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        progressDialog.show();

                        Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();

                        final String acesstoken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                        // App code
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                        try {
                                            //String user_name = (object.has("first_name") ? object.getString("first_name") : "") + "." + (object.has("last_name") ? object.getString("last_name") : "");
                                            String user_name = object.has("name") ? object.getString("name") : "";
                                            String user_image = "";
                                            if (object.has("picture")) {
                                                JSONObject ob = object.getJSONObject("picture");
                                                if (ob != null) {
                                                    if (ob.has("data")) {
                                                        JSONObject ob2 = ob.getJSONObject("data");
                                                        user_image = ob2.has("url") ? ob2.getString("url") : "";
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }

                                            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                                            mPresenter.signInFaceBook(object.getString("id"), acesstoken, user_name, user_image, token);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("LoginActivity", e.getMessage());

                                        }
                                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture.width(350).height(350),email,first_name,last_name");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        //NavigationManager.goToMainActivity(SplashActivity.this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.e("facebook error", error.toString());
                        //NavigationManager.goToMainActivity(SplashActivity.this);
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    }




    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public void handleSuccessfulLogin(String username) {
        progressDialog.hide();
        //NavigationManager.goToMainActivity(SplashActivity.this);

        if(username == null)
        {
//            NavigationManager.goToMainActivity(SplashActivity.this);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddUserNameActivity.class));

        }else{
            if(username.equals("")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AddUserNameActivity.class));
            }else{
                NavigationManager.goToMainActivity(LoginActivity.this);
            }
        }
        this.finish();
    }

    public void showError() {
        progressDialog.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    public void setPresenter(LoginContract.Presenter presenter) {
        mPresenter = presenter;
    }


    private void openFriendProfile( final String profile_id)
    {
        try {

            BlabberApplication app = (BlabberApplication) getApplication();

            Call<User> call = ConnectionManager.getApiManager().getProfile(app.getUserDataRepositoryComponent().getDataRepository().getUserId(),
                    app.getUserDataRepositoryComponent().getDataRepository().getAuthKey(), profile_id);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    User profileResponse = response.body();

                    if (profileResponse != null) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("user_id", Integer.parseInt(profileResponse.getUserData().getId()));
                        intent.putExtra("profile_type", "id_profile");
                        //intent.putExtra("user_name", profileResponse.getUserData().getName());
                        //intent.putExtra("user_image", profileResponse.getUserData().getProfilePhoto());

                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }

    private void openBusiness(final String business_id)
    {


        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"in openBusiness with business_id: "+business_id);
        Intent bintent = new Intent(com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity.this, com.blabber.app.business_details.BusinessDetailsActivity.class);
        bintent.putExtra("businessId", Integer.parseInt(business_id));
        startActivity(bintent);
        finish();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"in openBusiness should be staarted");

    }
}
```

Error

```
04-12 17:14:40.020 18930-18930/com.blabber.app E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blabber.app/com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.blabber.app.login.LoginContract$View
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.blabber.app.login.LoginContract$View
                                                                        at com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:161)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
04-12 17:14:40.021 18930-18992/com.blabber.app W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
04-12 17:14:40.021 18930-18992/com.blabber.app I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 7ms
04-12 17:14:40.024 18930-18992/com.blabber.app D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=2018, _sc=SplashActivity, _si=-8379143149063394155}]
04-12 17:14:40.091 18930-18992/com.blabber.app D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1492010080020, fatal=1}]
04-12 17:14:40.242 18930-18930/com.blabber.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.blabber.app, PID: 18930
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blabber.app/com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.blabber.app.login.LoginContract$View
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.blabber.app.login.LoginContract$View
                                                                     at com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:161)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blabber.app.login.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.blabber.app.login.LoginContract$View`

Comment: Seems like your Activity does not implement LoginContract as it should

Comment: loginPresenterModule(new LoginPresenterModule((LoginContract.View) this)).build().inject(this);
    Here you are casting an Activity into LoginContract.View which is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is happening because your trying to cast LoginActivity to LoginContract,

Here is the exact place where you are doing that casting,

```
DaggerLoginComponent.builder().dataRepositoryComponent(((BlabberApplication) getApplication()).getUserDataRepositoryComponent())
               .loginPresenterModule(new LoginPresenterModule((LoginContract.View) this))
```

Comment: This let me to go to LoginContract.java to verify the login. So, what is the solution for it? I am learning android as well.